# Can not set font for html2pdf in Laravel app

Tags: laravel, html2pdf

In laravel 5.7 app I work with spipu/html2pdf 5.2 to generate piece of html/bootstrap code
into pdf file and I have a problem with font definition

My pages use Roboto font, but if I make :

```
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','en', true, 'UTF-8');
$html2pdf->addFont('Roboto', '', public_path('/fonts/roboto/Roboto_regular.ttf'));
```

I have font in my app /fonts/roboto/Roboto_regular.ttf
and I can preview it : https://prnt.sc/tgcgjq

```
$html2pdf->WriteHTML(htmlspecialchars_decode($pdf_content));
$html2pdf->Output($save_to_file,'F');
```

But I got error :

```
TCPDF ERROR: The font definition file has a bad format: /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/the-box-booking/public/fonts/roboto/Roboto_regular.ttf
```

The difference in path is that I use links :

```
ln  -s   /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot  /_wwwroot
```

If I try to use times font(which I want to use for generated pdf file) as

```
$html2pdf->addFont('times');
```

I got error :

```
TCPDF ERROR: Could not include font definition file: &#039
```

looks like in last case fontname is not set , but I do not know how have I to set it ?
I have times set in my OS, I suppose I do not to put it under /public/fonts/?

Thanks!